Excel Populate Dependency on Task Number

Hi all, need the expertise in VBA to automate this. To auto populate the dependency table base on task that has overlap
Every Task Number will have list of task as per populated in Task Detail Sheet.
Dependency will be mark as 1 as long as there is overlapped in task tied to the task number.
At the moment, i have to populate the table 1 by 1 and every single cell is manually done with formula, every time there is new item added to the task detail sheet, i have to manually update the dependency table again.

I would be looking at if() with match(), you will also likely need iferror()

Use Tables. Then your formulas will auto-populate.

I tried using combination of INDEX, MATCH, COUNTIFS, but they dont really loop the entire record/array to compare every single task.

Try this formula in cell H3 and copy it to all the cells in the table.
=IF($G3<>H$2,IF(SUM(IFERROR(MATCH(IF($G$10:$G$17=$G3,$H$10:$H$17,1/0),IF($G$10:$G$17=H$2,$H$10:$H$17,1/0),0),0))>0,1,""),"")


Assuming no version constraints as per your tags, this can be done with formulas and formatting.
Given your data in a Table named TaskTbl:

You can enter the following formulas:
L1: =TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(taskTbl[TaskNumber])))
K2: =SORT(UNIQUE(taskTbl[TaskNumber]))

L2: =IF(
    $K2 = L$1,
    "",
    --LET(
        ts, taskTbl[[Task]:[Task]],
        tns, taskTbl[[TaskNumber]:[TaskNumber]],
        t, FILTER(ts, tns = L$1),
        m, OR(BYROW(t, LAMBDA(arr, OR((ts = arr) * (tns = $K2))))),
        m
    )
)

Select the formula in L2 and fill down as far as needed, then select that column and fill across.
The rest is just formatting.

